# How can I return a bitmap from SQLite database

Tags: c#, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android, sqlite.net

I have images on my server I want to download these images and store them in a local database (using SQLite) then I want to use these images locally.

So I've stored an image as bitmap to my SQLite Database, and I need to retrieve it from that database as bitmap too not as bytes.

This is my code..

Getting the image from url:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl1(string url)
{
    Bitmap imagebitmap = null;
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("..." + url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            imagebitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    return imagebitmap;
}
```

Using SQLite to create a local database:

```
// SQLite.. Creating database to store images 
private class MainDatabase
{
    // Constructor
    public MainDatabase()
    {
        if(!System.IO.File.Exists(folder))
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
            db.CreateTable<Image>();
        }
    }

    // Create database
    string folder = System.IO.Path.Combine
            (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
            "imagesDatabase.db");

    // Create Table
    [Table("Image")]
    public class Image
    {
        [Column("_id"), PrimaryKey , AutoIncrement]
        public int _id { set; get; }

        [Column("_image")]
        public Bitmap _image { set; get; }
        }

        //Insert data
        public void Insert(Bitmap image)
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
            var imageColumn = new Image();
            imageColumn._image = image;
            db.Insert(imageColumn);

        }

        //Retrieving data

        public Bitmap GetImageById(int id)
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);

            var image = from p in db.Table<Image>()
                        where p._id == id
                        select p._image;

            return image; // doesn't work   
        }
    }
```

I want to return it by its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I've stored an image as bitmap to my SQLite Database, and I need to retrieve it from that database as bitmap too not as bytes.

Bitmap can not be stored directly in SQLite. And I got unsupported type error when running your codes. The only way to store `Bitmap` in SQLite is to store and retrieve it in byte array. But you can wrap the convertion process in your methods and pass Bitmap directly in your Activity:

```
public class MainDatabase
{
    // Constructor
    public MainDatabase()
    {
        //if (!System.IO.File.Exists(folder))
        //{
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
            db.CreateTable<Image>();
        //}
    }

    // Create database
    string folder = System.IO.Path.Combine
            (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
            "imagesDatabase.db");

    // Create Table
    [Table("Image")]
    public class Image
    {
        [Column("_id"), PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int _id { set; get; }

        [Column("_image")]
        public byte[] _image { set; get; }// store the image with byte[]
    }

    public byte[] GetBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap image)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    //Insert data
    public int Insert(Bitmap image)
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
        var imageColumn = new Image();
        imageColumn._image = GetBitmapAsByteArray(image);
        return db.Insert(imageColumn);
    }

    //Retrieving data

    public Bitmap GetImageById(int id)
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(folder);
        Image image=db.Find<Image>(id);
        // return the decoded Bitmap
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image._image, 0, image._image.Length);
    }
}
```